# Scrollable JPanel Without a Layout Manager

Tags: java, swing, layout, jpanel, scrollable

I want to display a sinusoid on a vertically and horizontally scrollable JPanel. How can I achieve this without a layout manager?

Please see the code below. I need a vertical scrollbar to see the bottom part of the sinusoid.

It is important that layout managers are not used.

Thanks in advance.

```
package drawsinus;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;

public class DrawSinus extends JPanel
{
       private static double[] x;
       private static double[] y;
       private static JFrame frame = new JFrame();
       private static JPanel panel = new DrawSinus(); 
       
       public void paintComponent(Graphics g) 
       {
             super.paintComponent(g);
      
             Image img = generateSinus();
             g.drawImage(img, 20,20, this);
     
       }
       private Image generateSinus() 
       {
      
             BufferedImage bufferedImage = new BufferedImage(600, 600, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
             Graphics g = bufferedImage.getGraphics();
             x = new double[200];
             y = new double[200];
             for (int t=0; t<=199; t++)
             {                 
                 x[t]= (double)t;
                 y[t] = 300*Math.sin(2*Math.PI*1*t/200);              
             }
             for (int t=0; t<x.length; t++)
             {                   
                 g.fillOval((int)x[t] + bufferedImage.getWidth()/2, -1*((int)y[t]) + bufferedImage.getHeight()/2, 20, 20);                         
             }
            
             return bufferedImage;
      
       }
       public static void main(String[] args) 
       {
             frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
             frame.setSize(800,600);
             frame.setLayout(null);
             frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
             frame.setVisible(true);

             panel.setLayout(null);
             panel.setBounds(20, 20, 600, 400);
             panel.setBackground(Color.BLACK);

             frame.add(panel);

             JScrollPane scrPane = new JScrollPane(panel);
             scrPane.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
             scrPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
             frame.add(scrPane);

             new DrawSinus().generateSinus();
            
       }
    
}
```

Comment: @ user16320675. Thanks for the corrections. 1) Last line removed; 2) panel is only added to scrPane; 3) preferred size is set for panel; 4) Bounds of scrPane are set; 5) frame is set visible at the last line (I think that's what you meant). Now, I can see the scrollbars, but I can only scroll a little bit. I need to scroll and see the bottom of the sinusoid. With layout managers I get unexpected results. I can't put the components to the correct coordinates and I can't set the size and bounds of components. That's the reason why I prefer manually adjusting the components.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here a minimal example of how it *can* be done.

The component inside the scroll pane must implement the `Scrollable` interface or have the preferred size set, used by the scroll pane to determine the size of its viewport view.

I preferred overriding `getPreferredSize`, so it *dynamically* changes if the image is changed (not possible in this minimal example) and to avoid having the preferred size *externally* changed by `setPreferredSize()`.

```java
public class DrawSinus2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Swing's Thread Police: All Swing components and related classes, unless
        // otherwise documented, must be accessed on the event dispatching thread.
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(DrawSinus2::initGUI);
    }
    
    private static void initGUI() {
        // Panel to draw image
        JPanel sinusPanel = new JPanel() {
            private final Image image = generateSinus();
            
            @Override
            protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
                super.paintComponent(g);
                if (image != null) {
                    g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, this);
                }
            }
            
            // Preferred size used by scroll pane
            @Override
            public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
                return new Dimension(image.getWidth(this), image.getHeight(this));
            }
        };

        // Scroll pane containing the image panel
        JScrollPane scrPane = new JScrollPane(sinusPanel);
        scrPane.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
        scrPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
        scrPane.setBounds(0, 0, 600, 400);

        // Main frame displaying the scroll pane
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLayout(null);
        frame.setSize(800, 600);
        frame.add(scrPane);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
    
    private static Image generateSinus() {
        // generate and return some image
    }
}
```